# Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError

Tags: bluetooth

I have Ubuntu mate 17.10, I try to connect my Bluetooth speaker but i keep getting this error

Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError

It pair but the connection goes on and off

could please someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe could you test this :

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

and reboot.

Source : [Peripherique audio bluetooth Xubuntu 15-10](https://sansindiscretion.fr/blog/2015-12-14-utiliser-peripherique-audio-bluetooth-xubuntu-15-10)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after an update and I was not able to connect to Bluetooth. It was connecting well before an update.

```
    Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError:
    connect error: Permission denied
```

If you get above error, just unpair the device and pair it again. It will ask for permission, give permission, then you will be able to connect.